# Extending a generic model extending from ActiveRecord::Base

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, extending-classes

I have a generic `Service` model which contains a few generic functions including a few to be overridden by 'actual services'.

**service.rb**

```
class Service < ActiveRecord::Base
  def get_line_items
    raise "Not Implemented"
  end
end
```

I then have a model extending the `Service` model:

**misc_service.rb**

```
class MiscService < Service
  attr_accessible :retail_price
  def get_line_items
    return [{"Misc Service - 1" => retail_price}]
  end
end
```

However, when trying to access the MiscService model in the rails console, I'm getting the error:

```
:001 > service = MiscService.first
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Table 'devdb.services' doesn't exist: SHOW FULL FIELDS FROM `services`
```

I can see that's happening because it's the Service model extending `ActiveRecord::Base`, so is there something I can do in the `Service` model to cause any models extending it to instead use their own table? I'd prefer to have that happen from the `Service` model and not have to explicitly define it in any models extending it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has nothing to do with sub classes. Your service table itself isn't ready. Make sure you have migration file ready and run `$ rake db migrate`

Comment: I don't want there to be a `Service` table now or ever - I just want `MiscService` and any other services I define in future to inherit all the methods from `Service` while using their own tables all of which will have unique schemas.

Comment: If you want methods only, use module and include/extend them, and then models will act like service. Do not use inherits.

Comment: That seems very sensible. Thanks